# Powershell // CSV-Output in foreach

Tags: powershell-4.0, scom

I´m working with SCOM (SystemCenterOperationsManager) and wrote a little script for an scheduled task.

It should collect all `NEW ( ResolutionState = 0 )` Alerts and filter them with my Wildcard rule.

It will Change the resolution state for all collected alerts to an specific Resolution state.

**My Problem:**

To get an Report for all the Chosen alerts I want to generate an "Out-file"
Where should I place it ?

Here is my code:

```
if ($LastHourAlerts)
{
   foreach($Alert in $LastHourAlerts)
   {      
   $newState = $null

   switch -wildcard ($Alert.Name) 
      {
      "Operations Manager failed to start a process" { $newState = 255 } 
      "Operations Manager failed to check the state of a service" { $newState = 255 }
      "Operations Manager failed to run a WMI query" { $newstate =255 }
      "Interface Utilization Alert" { $newState = 15 }
      "Veeam VMware: Datastore Provisioning Analysis" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware Collector: VMware connection data processing errors" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware Collector: VMware connection is unavailable" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: Virtual Machine Memory Usage Analysis" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: Virtual Machine CPU Usage Analysis" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: Virtual Machine Memory Ballooning and Swapping Analysis" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: Virtual Machine Storage Latency Analysis" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: Virtual Machine Consolidation Needed status Alarm" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: Maintenance Mode Tracker" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: vSphere Host Storage Commands Failed Analysis" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: vSphere Host Network Packet Loss Analysis" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: vSphere Host Memory Swapping Analysis" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: vSphere Host Memory Usage Analysis" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: vSphere Host Kernel Latency Analysis" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: vSphere Cluster Memory Overcommit Analysis" { $newState = 17 }
      "Veeam VMware: VM customization failed" { $newState = 17 }

      }


      if($newState -ne $null)
         {
         $Alert.ResolutionState = $newState
         $Alert.Update(“Resolution State changed automatically by Automation”)              
         }
     }    
}
```

I tríed something like this in the end of the if Loop:

```
$Alert.Name | Out-File ("$path\" + "Report.csv") -Append
```

Although it takes the name, but writes only the name of the first alarm object in the number of all processed alarms. For example:

5 different Alerts:

```
Operations Manager failed to start a process
Interface Utilization Alert
Veeam VMware: VM customization failed
Veeam VMware: Virtual Machine CPU Usage Analysis
Veeam VMware Collector: VMware connection is unavailable
```

and that´s in the .csv:

```
Operations Manager failed to start a process
Operations Manager failed to start a process
Operations Manager failed to start a process
Operations Manager failed to start a process
Operations Manager failed to start a process
```

Is there a better way to get a data output? Also, I would not only like to have the `$Alert.Name` but 
`$Alert.Name, $Alert.TimeRaised, $ResolutionState`.

Comment: Do these actually have a resolution state 0? Check with `$Alert | Format-Table Name, ResolutionState -AutoSize`.

Comment: No, they have received their proper predetermined value like: ` switch -wildcard ($Alert.Name) 
      {
      "Operations Manager failed to start a process" { $newState = 255 }`

Answer (score 0):

Put something like this at the end of your loop:

```
if ($Alert.ResolutionState -eq 0) {
  $Alert.Name | Out-File 'C:\path\to\your.txt' -Append
}
```

Comment: Tanks you for the answer, but it´s not what i´m looking for.